# Get arrays in different variables in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I execute below code:

```
print_r($marks);
```

Output is:

```
Array ( [Dane] => 1 [Mary] => 6 [Jon] => 2) Array ( [Dane] => 3 [Mary] => 2 [Jon] => 1) Array ( [Dane] => 2 [Mary] => 7 [Jon] => 1)
```

Suppose if many subjects are there (here in example 2 are there). How to get a output as given below ?. I want to store marks in each subject in different variables.

Desired output:

```
$subject1=Array ( [Dane] => 1 [Mary] => 6 [Jon] => 2) 
$subject2=Array ( [Dane] => 2 [Mary] => 7 [Jon] => 1)
.
.
.
$subjectn=Array ( [Dane] => 1 [Mary] => 8 [Jon] => 2)
```

Comment: There's no need to do it. You can take each subarray with it's index - `$marks[0]`, `$marks[1]`, etc

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to achieve as a whole? Generating your "desired output" doesn't really make sense and there is more than likely a much better way to achieve your overall goal.

Comment: @RossWilson i want to store marks of students in each subject in separate variable and then have to save in database separately as comma separated.

Comment: use echo "<pre>";print_r($marks); and provide well formatted array output in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop your array and create new arrays:

```
$marks = array(
    array( 'Dane' => 1, 'Mary' => 6, 'Jon' => 2),
    array( 'Dane' => 3, 'Mary' => 2, 'Jon' => 1),
    array( 'Dane' => 2, 'Mary' => 7, 'Jon' => 1)
);

foreach($marks as  $mark_index => $mark){
    ${"subject" . $mark_index} = $mark;     
}
```

and the result will be new arrays $subject1, $subject2, $subject3 with values of each array.